# Why doesn't the standard require that struct members be padded minimally?

Tags: c, padding

The standard doesn't seem impose any padding requirements on struct members, even though it [does prohibit reordering (6.7.2.1p6)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p6). How likely is it that a C platform will not pad minimally, i.e., not add only the minimum amount of padding needed to make sure the next member (or instance of the same struct, if this is the last member) is sufficiently aligned for its type?

Is it even sensible of the standard not to require that padding be minimal?

I'm asking because this lack of a padding guarantee seems to prevent me from portably representing serialized objects as structs (even if I limit myself to just `uint8_t` arrays as members, compilers seem to be allowed to add padding in between them), and I'm finding it a little weird to have to resort to offset arithmetic there.

Comment: Serialization was always a pain in C. If you limit yourself to `uint8_t`, then just use an array. If you don't - the minimal padding won't help.

Comment: If you use `uint8_t` you have already limited yourself to computers having an 8-bit byte. How portable do you want to be?

Comment: It is true that the standard doesn't specify any requirement regarding the padding and the compilers may or may noy apply padding but almost each compiler has an option (pragma or attribute) to prevent padding for specific datatype. Usually called as *pack*, ie: `pack(1)`.

Comment: @BoPersson POSIX portable. POSIX mandates uin8_t. (I mean I could use unsigned char and play with CHAR_BIT, but I don't really care about portability beyond POSIX).

Comment: Also the definition of "minimal" padding may vary between processor architectures, so it wouldn't actually standardise anything.

Comment: @GemTaylor But char arrays should be 1-aligned so no padding, unless  I'm much mistaken. With char/uint8_t arrays + a minimal padding requirement I think I'd have guaranteed offsets.

Comment: I agree that it would be very difficult to implement strings if char arrays were not packed, but that doesn't mean that two char members in a struct need a guarantee to be packed together, as you should "never" be considering them as concatenatable.

Comment: *this lack of a padding guarantee seems to prevent me from portably representing serialized objects as structs* -- yes, that's a well known fact, that's why Google is using protocol buffers, for example. If Google is doing this, then you can rest assured that struct in-memory layout cannot be guaranteed. If you're asking "why" the standard is written this way (and it seems so from the title), I am not sure this question fits SO.

Comment: "lack of a padding guarantee seems to prevent me from portably representing serialized objects as structs" -->  posting an example of how code  prevents portability would add clarity.  Perhaps we together,  can portably representing a serialized objects as a `struct`.

Comment: @Groo Yeah, it's not a great, speculation-free question. But at least the comments have helped me shed some light on things (Thanks everybody!) (I've never needed to serializes structs across networks before  and in the thing I'm making it's only of marginal important -- to make it complete, which means I don't want  to spend too much time researching it). I'll simply do it the foolproof way (offsets).

Comment: Darwin sorts this out.  A compiler that fumbles this is not going to be very popular.  They don't.

Comment: @PSkocik: Protocol buffers are, actually, one of the most foolproof ways to do serialization in C. You get a compact binary representation (e.g. [varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints), no endianness issues to worry about, optional members, versioning support, and several very efficient implementations (e.g. zero-alloc implementations for embedded systems), ported to various languages. Regarding last two points, I've used [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) to exchange data between an embedded system written in C and a C# service without issues.

Comment: Why the close vote? This seems like a perfectly cromulent question. Down/Close-voting without explanation helps no one. How can they learn, if you won't tell them what - in your opinion - wrong?

Comment: @Mawg: I'd wager there are members here who do not want issues like this to be discussed at all.  I do not think it is any company astroturfing or anyone trolling, just people feeling unsure/uncomfortable around concepts and questions they'd really prefer to consider inviolate gospel. I expect my answer will garner quite a few downvotes (more!) for a similar reason, and also for berating Microsoft for their efforts wrt. the C standard committee.

Comment: @Mawg If you click on where it says "close(1)" it will show the reason that the person voted.  In this case "primarily opinion based", which seems accurate to me because it is asking people's opinion about the likelihood of compilers being obtuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How likely is it that a C platform will not pad minimally, i.e., not add only the minimum amount of padding needed to make sure the next member (or instance of the same struct, if this is the last member) is sufficiently aligned for its type?

Essentially, the "extra" padding may allow significant compiler optimizations.

Unfortunately, I don't know if any compilers actually do that (and therefore cannot provide any estimate on its likelihood of occurring).

As a simple example, consider a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture, where the ABI states that string literals and character arrays are aligned to 32-bit or 64-bit boundary.  Many of the C library functions are (also) implemented by the C compiler itself; see e.g. [these lists for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).  The compiler can track the parameters to see if they refer to a string literal or (the beginning of a) character array, and if so, replace e.g. `strcmp()` with an optimized built-in version (which does the comparison in 32-bit units, rather than char-at-a-time).

As a more complicated example, consider a RISC hardware architecture, where unaligned byte access is slower than aligned native word access. (For example, the former may be implemented in hardware as the latter, followed by a bit shift.)  Such an architecture could have an ABI that requires all structure members to be word-aligned. Then, the C compiler would be required to add more-than-minimal padding.

Traditionally, the C standards committee has been very careful to not exclude any kind of hardware architecture from correctly implementing the language.

> Is it even sensible of the standard not to require that padding be minimal?

The purpose of the C standard used to be to ensure that C code would behave in the same manner if compiled with different compilers, and to allow implementation of the language on any sufficiently capable hardware architecture.  In that sense, it is very *sensible* for the standard not to require minimal padding, as some ABIs may require more than minimal padding for whatever reason.

With the introduction of the Microsoft ["extensions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish), the purpose of the C standard has shifted significantly, to binding C to C++ to ensure a C++ compiler can compile C code with minimal differences to C++ compilation, and to provide interfaces that can be marketed as "safer" with the actual purpose of balkanizing developers and binding them to a single vendor implementation. Because this is contrary to the previous purpose of the standard, and it is clearly non-*sensible* to standardize single-vendor functions like fscanf_s() while not standardizing multi-vendor functions like getline(), it may not be possible to define what *sensible* means anymore in the context of the C standard.  It definitely does not match "good judgment"; it probably now refers to "being perceptible by the senses".

> I'm asking because this lack of a padding guarantee seems to prevent me from portably representing serialized objects as structs

You are making the same mistake C programmers make, over and over again. Structs are **not** suitable for representing serialized objects.  You **should not** use a struct to represent a network object, or a file header, because of the C struct rules.

Instead, you should use a simple character buffer, and either accessor functions (to extract or pack each member or field from the buffer), or conversion functions (to convert the buffer contents to a struct and vice versa).

The underlying reason why even experienced programmers like the asker still would prefer to use a struct instead, is that the accessors/conversion involves a lot of extra code; having the compiler do it instead would be much better: less code, simpler code, easier to maintain.

And I agree. It would even be quite straightforward, if a new keyword, say `serialized_struct` was introduced; to introduce a serialized data structure with completely different member rules to traditional C structs. (Note that this support would not affect e.g. linking at all, so it really is not as complicated as one might think.) Additional attributes or keywords could be used to specify explicit byte order, and the compiler would do all the conversion details for us, in whatever way the compiler sees best for the specific architecture it compiler for.  This support would only be available for new code, but it would be hugely beneficial in cutting down on interoperability issues -- and it would make a lot of serialization code simpler!

Unfortunately, when you combine the C standard committee's traditional dislike to adding new keywords, and the overall direction change from interoperability to vendor lock-in, there is no chance at all for anything like this to be included in the C standard.

Of course, as described in the comments, there are lots of C libraries that implement one serialization scheme or other.  I've even written a few myself (for rather peculiar use cases, though).  A sensible approach (poor pun intended) would be to pick a vibrant one (well maintained, with a lively community around the library), and use it.

Comment: Heh, it seems some people **really** don't like facts about the C standard committee brought up.  I do not mind disagreement, but if you do, rather than just downvote, do take the time to explain what it is that you disagree with, either by commenting, or putting up your own answer.  The reason is, otherwise there is no way to determine whether downvotes have a basis (as in there being an error in this answer), or if it is just because someone doesn't *like* the answer. The former is very useful, the latter is just noise.

Comment: Disagree that "the purpose of the C standard has shifted significantly, to binding C to C++ to ensure a C++ compiler can compile C code with minimal differences to C++ compilation,"  . If anything, C and C++ are further apart now than they ever have been.  The C standard has never had any C++ compatibility features.

Comment: Also, complaining about the optional C11 Annex K has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the topic of this question.

Comment: @M.M: C11 was a step in a completely different direction to C99. It did not codify existing practice, but created completely new definitions, from atomics to Annex K. Before C11, GCC, Intel CC, Pathscale, and PGI C compilers all implemented the `__sync_` atomic operators. C11 added atomic type support using C++ memory order semantics without any previous C compiler support.

Comment: That was a case of re-using existing work; not language compatibility. Someone already did the work to lay out a well defined memory model for atomics so the C working group may as well use it instead of reinventing the wheel.  BTW this still has nothing to do with structure padding, SO isn't a discussion forum

Comment: @M.M: Yes, C and C++ are further apart now than ever before, but that is because of rapid changes in C++. And that exactly is the reason vendors like Microsoft want to push C towards C++, and not for example towards including POSIX.1 features (in the hosted environment): these vendors want to minimize the effort they need to keep their C++ compilers compatible with C.  Everything in the C11 is a clear example of this, and Annex K is the most egregious step by Microsoft, if one considers that vendors previous behaviour.

Comment: Annex K is optional and nobody else supports it except MS , so I disagree with your position there

Comment: @M.M: I brought the C standard and its development up in my answer, because it is important point if one considers *what future C standards might include*.  Having an Annex K in C11 at all is a clear indication of the intents of the standards committee.  I really do not see why you are so naïve regarding the standards development, nor why you do not see how the stated question intrinsically depends on what direction future C standards are likely to go.  Perhaps, instead of just downvoting, you could write your own answer?

Comment: I didn't vote but thanks for the assumption. Also, this question is about likely behaviour of compilers, not future standards directions.  It seems unlikely to me that a future standard will *mandate* that compilers cannot use the padding regimes they currently use. Such a requirement would just be ignored .

Comment: @M.M: You're welcome. I understood the question to be not just about likely behaviour of compilers, but about why the current standards leave so much about struct padding up to the compiler, and about how one might go about predicting how that might change. Do note that C99 introducing exact width integer types (intN_t, uintN_t) and related types, was a similar change to integer types as discussed here for struct types (disallowing padding, requiring specific (two's complement) representation). I honestly believe all of this is pertinent to the question at hand.

Comment: OK, the stuff about architectures architectures aligning even bytes makes sense. I looked and the standard actually only requires that the alignment of char types be weakest not necessarily 1. Thanks for answering.